# There is an unclosed literal string. Line 1, position 12284

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have this class generated from a web-service:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class RequestMessage 
{    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007", Order=0)]
    public Helper.RequestType Request;

    public RequestMessage() {
    }                
}
```

I'm trying to create an XmlDocument by:

```
XmlDocument xReq = new XmlDocument();

DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(RequestMessage));
using (MemoryStream memStm = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(memStm))
    {
        //xnameSpace.Add("ns0", "urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007");
        serializer.WriteObject(xw, oReq);

        memStm.Position = 0;
        xReq.Load(memStm);
    }
}
```

But i'm getting an error: "There is an unclosed literal string. Line 1, position 12284." on "xReq.Load(memStm);" line.

I'm using UTF-8 encoding, but I've read that is the default of "XmlSerializerNamespaces"..

What can be the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to flush the `XmlWriter` before reading from it:

```
serializer.WriteObject(xw, oReq);
// Make sure all the XML has been written to the stream.
xw.Flush();
memStm.Position = 0;
xReq.Load(memStm);
```

Otherwise the last part of the serialized XML is not written to the stream and which in your case results in an opening quote without a closing quote.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the program was still holding on to the XML file hence getting this error. Ending the program solved the problem.